# Debug a deployed smart contract

Tags: solidity, remix, blockchain, fantom

Please tell me about some methodologies or tools for debugging already deployed smart contracts, as some crypto protocols don't support testnets. I am currently using a cheap blockchain (Fantom) for testing purposes, but it is difficult to find bugs. Hence, I need a solution for debugging smart contracts.

---

Thank you for the responses. The problem is that testing smart contracts on a local environment or on a testnet isolates them from the external world, which is important in DeFi development.

I would like to know if it's possible to debug a smart contract like we do locally with Remix or Truffle. I was unable to run debugging for a already deployed smart contract using these specified tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can either run your tests using forks or you can use a tool similar to tenderly to simulate transactions.
https://tenderly.co/

Comment: Tenderly is excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I use `hardhat` for product prototyping. It supports test coverage against local chain which works almost immediately with much clear error messaging.

Also I left `goerly` testnet and deployed a private chain on VM hosted locally. It allows me to take control on mining speed and solves the issue with limited ether.

Recently I heard about several solutions of simulated blockchains, but haven't tried them yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are various tools available to debug your SC

[**`Remix`**](https://remix.ethereum.org/) IDE for solidity it has an integrated debugger for contract code.

[**`Truffle`**](https://truffleframework.com/) A framework for Ethereum, used for testing and debugging smart contracts.

[**`Geth Console`**](https://ethereum.org/cli) It has a built-in JavaScript environment and can be used to debug smart contracts.

[**`Ganache`**](https://truffleframework.com/ganache) It provides a secure and isolated environment for testing and debugging of Ethereum based dapps without the need for a real network.

Answer (score 0):

I believe using **Hardhat** is the best option out there to either test your own code locally or on a testnet or fork mainnet to run tests on an already deployed contract.